# Not able to use imake in mingw

Tags: mingw

I am trying to build my source of linux using mingw. But when i use imake command to generate make file its throwing error imake command not foiund.

Could any one help which package i have to install in mingw and how to install it ?

Answer (score 0):

imake is part of xorg. You need some mingw-Port of the xorg development tools to use imake on windows. When you are cross-compiling on linux with windows a target, you need to install xutils-dev(name of the debian package, might be some other for your distro).